# Most short hand, efficient way to do this file path construction

Tags: php

So i'm being pretty hacky here but it works (i welcome any other suggestions) - i'm hoping someone can show me a shorter, more compact way to execute the following:

```
$directories = explode('/',trim(str_replace(trim(basename($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'])),"",trim( $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] ) ),'/'));
foreach ($directories as $key => $directory) {$torootlevel .= "../";}

require_once($torootlevel . "config.php");
```

The code basically checks where you are in the application and iterates through the directory structure to get the file path to the root of the app. Its the first and only time i use this code as it loads my config.php file which provides me constants for paths that are used further down the code.

```
...
require_once(DIR_APP . "inc/class.interface.php");
```

Comment: so you want unreadable code why?

Comment: Well, no... I want compact code...

Comment: Hehe, I was just wondering what this actually does. Please provide input and output.

Comment: I have edited my post. I hope this helps.

Comment: Why no use document root instead of messy `../` something like : `define('DIR_APP',$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/your_app_path')`, but i really think that a better option it's that you go for PSR-4 autoloader

Comment: I use a router usually so the only entry point to the app is index.php in which case finding the root path is easy, take a look at this one: http://altorouter.com/ I'll give it some thought and see if I can create a better solution though.

Comment: @OsDev that makes good sense given they have access to this configuration setting.

Comment: ok so what advantage do you think this  "compact" code actually has

Comment: @Dagon Likely using it on every view / page to set application configuration variables and the likes, so guessing that they would like a simple one liner to start things off with. There's better ways to accomplish this task though and i'd personally spend a bit of time investigating them first.

Comment: Thought about it and @OsDev gives the most practical solution for this, use DOCUMENT_ROOT if possible as it does what you require.

Comment: Yeah, don't mind me. This works just fine it seems. require_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/config.php"); My apologies...

Comment: A good developer has the ability to solve problems in different ways but also knows when these paths are not working out and can scrap the idea so as to move on with a better solution. You've done nothing wrong here, doing good actually :)